# How to hide my website to the public so only I can see it?

Tags: django, nginx, gunicorn, digital-ocean

Creating a Django website with Digital Ocean (Nginx, Guncorn) - and would like to know how to show a blank page until I've finished development.

So when someone other than myself visits my website, I want them to see a page saying "Site under construction" or something. Advice appreciated.

Comment: Point the page that show's the coming soon message or try and add a profile flag to which the website forwards connection to the blank page.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are a lot of ways to achieve this, but I'll outline two.

1. **The Easiest Approach** - Deploy a static single html page that says site under construction until you are ready for others to see the app.
2. **Probably more useful** - Decorate every view with

   from django.contrib.admin.views.decorators import staff_member_required

   @staff_member_required

To have this work properly make sure that you setup you login page in settings to redirect to a page which only shows "Under Construction".  This way you can login through admin but anybody else will just see "Under Construction".